# Is there any way to code a button which transforms an image on the same page with css/html?

Tags: html, css, image, button

I'm programming a site which goes about our solar system. I made a solar system in the middle of the webpage and I want to program some buttons which link to one of these planets which will transform the scale of the chosen planet when clicked on.

So my question is: How to link a button to an image?

I've already looked on the internet, but couldn't find a solution. I couldn't come up with a solution myself, as I am starting to learn css and html.

I think my code isn't needed to solve my problem.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! In reference to your comment of "I think my code isn't needed to solve my problem." that may be true but generally folks like seeing you've made some form of effort since while lots of people enjoy helping, they don't want to think they're just being used to do free work. Consider adding a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and will greatly increase your chances of receiving help. Cheers!

Comment: I don`t know if that is what you want, but you could use a link tag and reference the id of the image like
```html
<a href="#saturn">Saturn</a>
```

or maybe use something like this lib carousel
https://css-components.felipefialho.com/#component-carousel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a freebie example. Welcome to SO!

```js
scaleImg = (id) => {

  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  
  el.style.transform = 'scale(3)';

}
```

```css
#testy {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW9D.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 20%;
  transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="testy"></div>

<br/><br/>

<button onclick="scaleImg('testy')">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm trying to understand what the above codes means. I began copying the javascript in a htlm document with the <script> tag in the head ''section''. Do I now need to replace (id) with #testy? I tried looking for clear tutorials on the internet but there seems to be no clear one...

Comment: @opelxmax the `(id)` is a parameter passed from the method called from the button. You may want to browse some beginner tutorials and it will help give you a better grasp on things. Best of luck and welcome to SO!

Comment: @ChrisW. Ah I think I got it, it's just like a formula mathematical formula. So the ''Testy'' ID or any other ID written after scaleImg (for instance scaleImg(apple) gets inserted as the ID in the scaleIMG Javascript formula :D